# adding values from an object to a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an object that I obtained from an xml file and it contains a field of SeriesCode and ProductCodes associated with the specified Series code.

i.e.

```
SeriesCodeA
      prodCode1
      prodCode2
      prodCode3
SeriesCodeA
      prodCode4
      prodCode5
      prodCode6
```

I created a the following dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictSeries = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

The values from the object I want to add to the dictionary. So in other words I want to, for each series code added to the Dictionary key as a string value add the corresponding product codes as string values.

something like

```
foreach (var s in series)
{
    string code = s.SeriesCode;
    if (dictSeries.ContainsKey(code))
    {
        foreach (var l in s.ProductCodes)
        {
            dictSeries[code].Add(l);
        }
    }

}
```

The above is not quite right

How can I add the SeriesCodes as keys to the dictionary with the corresponding product codes as string values(List)?

Comment: What isn't "quite right" with the code you posted? How is it behaving vs. how you want it to behave?

Comment: Don't forget to initialize your list with `new List<string>()` otherwise you'll get a null reference exception :)

Comment: ToDictionary is also a good extension. Solves it inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LINQ` and [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) method to make it more readable:

```
var dictSeries = series.ToDictionary(x => x.SeriesCode, x => x.ProductCodes);
```

A assumed your `Series` class looks like that:

```
class Serie
{
    public string SeriesCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductCodes { get; set; }
}
```

Your code also will work, but needs few improvements:

```
foreach (var s in series)
{
    string code = s.SeriesCode;
    if (!dictSeries.ContainsKey(code))
    {
        dictSeries.Add(code, new List<string>());
    }

    foreach (var l in s.ProductCodes)
    {
        dictSeries[code].Add(l);
    }
}
```